# SP 2010 Search Error

Tags: 2010, search

I am facing following Error in SP2010 Search:

> http://pro1766:32843/3966a8bf4a4e4e338fda8adb4980a596/SearchService.svc could not be activated.​

The log error I am getting is as follows:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Microsoft.Office.Server.
>   Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.SetPropertiesOnQueryReader() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.OnInit(EventArgs e)
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.SetPropertiesOnQueryReader() at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.CoreResultsWebPart.OnInit(EventArgse)

Possible Solution I got from Googling is as follows:

This (Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEndpointAddress NotFoundException: There are no addresses available for this application) probably means that whatever you're trying to do, it can't find the appropriate web service.

This could be because the necessary services aren't started anywhere in the farm.
The required services are

1. SharePoint Server Search
2. Search Query and Site Settings Service

But I am not able to find it

Can someone please help!

Comment: Please supply more details regarding your setup, including crawl log files (find them in Search Service management in Central Administration), ULS Trace logs (find the path to the log files in CA > Monitoring > Configure Diagnostic logging). Also examine Application Event log for futher info. Then paste them into your question.

Comment: The error I mentioned appears  in Keyword Search link in Site Collection Settings. Will get logs & post it here shortly

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick check list I use when I can't get a service to work:

- Is the service running?
- Is the Secure Store Service
  provisioned and running?
- Is the Security Token Service
  provisioned and running?
- Is the State Service provisioned and
  running?
- Is the service applications
  associated with a proxy group?

Comment: ANd is the app pool running, or throwing errors and stopping again, etc. Good points!